# how to get the number of elements in the specified collection equal to the specified object, underscore?

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) library and wonder if I can get easily frequency of specific item in list.

For example, I have array:

```
var list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'];
```

I want something like:

```
var count_a = /*returnCountFunction*/(list, 'a'); // 2.
var count_b = /*returnCountFunction*/(list, 'b'); // 1.
```

I'm interesting only use  underscoreJS.

*Java has:* `Collections.frequency(list, "a");`

**[EDIT]**

Actually I had complicated list of objects but I wrote:

```
$scope.getUniqueBiz = function(list){    
        return _.chain(list)
      .pluck('biz_name')
       .unique()
      .value();    
    };
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`_.countBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#countBy):

> Sorts a list into groups and returns a count for the number of objects
>   in each group.

So this:

```
result = _.countBy(list);
```

Returns this (on your list):

> {a: 2, b: 1, c: 1}

From which you can grab:

```
result['a'];
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
_.filter(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'], function(item){ return item == 'a'; }).length;
```

Comment: Well, but its only works for `a`. `a` must enter as parameter but not hardcoded. thanks

Comment: In that case pass your parameter as context e.g. `var searchfor = 'a'; _.filter(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'], function(item){ return item == this; }, searchfor).length;`

Answer (score 1):

```
var search = 'a';
var result = _.reduce(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'], function(sum, letter) {
    return letter === search ? sum + 1 : sum;
  }, 0);
```